# Accessing and manipulating fields in Layer file

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer, mosaic-dataset

I am trying to update several fields in a mosaic dataset, to do this I am creating a mosaic layer and then running a loop over each row and calculating fields.

A `NAME` field contains a string which I would like to use to calculate several other fields. It is formatted like the following:

```
Project_2020_1x_YZ_Type_20200101_0900VLAT_102a
```

I would like to use split and use the output list indices in a field calculation (ie Project, Year and Date). The issue is I don't know to access the `NAME` field within a mosaic layer.

```
# create mosaic layer
mdl = arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management(md_path, "md_layer")

# calculate fields loop
print("Calculating fields in footprint...")
for lyr in mdl:
    split_name = lyr.NAME.split('_')
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "YEAR", ????, "PYTHON")
    print("Year calculated...")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "PROJECT",????, "PYTHON")
    print("Project calculated...")
```

It falls over at the first step - `split_name = lyr.NAME.split('_')`-

```
AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'NAME'
```

I would like to know the best approach to accessing specific fields within the mosaic layer.

Comment: `NAME` is not a property of an `arcpy.Layer` object. You likely want to access a field (in a DA SearchCursor) on the dataSource of the layer.

Comment: See the 1st example (which uses split) in the [help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm)

Comment: Thanking @Vince, I've started over with an UpdateCursor after being prompted by your reply and am having success. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the 1st example (which uses split) in the [help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm):

```
for lyr in mdl:  #Note replace PYTHON with PYTHON3 for ArcGIS Pro

    split_name = '!NAME!.split("_"){}'

    arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "YEAR", split_name.format('[1]'), "PYTHON")
    print("Year calculated...")

    arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "PROJECT", split_name.format('[0]'), "PYTHON")
    print("Project calculated...")

    arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr, "DATE", split_name.format('[5]'), "PYTHON")
    print("Date calculated...")
```

However... an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` will probably be quicker than 3x `arcpy.CalculateField_management` calls as you can calculate all fields required at once.